# How to implement YQL paging?

Tags: javascript, yql

I've read the YQL guide, and I keep reviewing http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-o...entables-paging  and I have been looking at a few examples, but I'm still left pretty confused how YQL paging works.

The problem that I am trying to tackle is creating a YQL open data table for the Mozilla labs Jetpack Gallery's jetpacks pages http://jetpackgallery.mozillalabs.com/jetpacks

You flip through the pages of jetpacks with the ?page query variable and there is an order_by query variable. You can only see 10 results per page.

Questions:

- List item
- Should I use  or  ?

  - How do I specify the query parameter that indicates the page? in this case it is the 'page' query parameter.
- I am assuming I should use: `<urls><url>http://jetpackgallery.mozillalabs.com/jetpacks</url></urls>` is this correct?
- In the execute element, I will need to extract the details for each jetpack on the page? if so how would I organize that for the response.object?

Can anyone provide some help? or perhaps point to a data table that I can look at as a reference? or better documentation on how paging works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be looking at the [paging model](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html#yql-opentables-paging) (Your link got compressed above, so I'm just putting it here.

When you use the paging with no `<execute></execute>` block specified, it will be used in the query string with the URL specified in `<url></url>`. Just play with the [Flickr Photo Search Example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-sample.html#yql-opentables-sample-flickr-photo-search), you have to run it in the Console with Diagnostics turned on to look at the changes in the URL. The `id` attribute is used to insert the number in the query. Just to illustrate here, the paging portion looks like this:

```
   <paging model="page">  
     <start id="page" default="0" />  
     <pagesize id="per_page" max="250" />  
     <total default="10" />  
   </paging>
```

For example, querying

```
select * from flickr.photos.search(10,20) where has_geo="true"`
```

The URL used was `http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&has_geo=true&page=1&per_page=30`. As you can see, it actually took the `page=1` but asked for `per_page=30` and internally truncated the first 10 results so that you get an offset of 10 and a total of 20 results.
The reason why YQL did this is because the model selected is `page`.

Another example, if you attempt to do this:

```
select * from flickr.photos.search(249,2) where has_geo="true"
```

YQL will retrieve both `...&page=1&per_page=250` and `...&page=2&per_page=250` <sub>(I've shortened the urls for illustration)</sub> as expected to get the results.

The paging variables are also defined in the global scope if you use JavaScript in `<execute></execute>` section. You can see this being used in the [flickr.photos.astro OpenData Table](http://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/flickr/flickr.photos.astro.xml).

I guess that should answer the question for you, since I see that [on GitHub](http://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/mozillalabs/jetpackgallery/mozillalabs.jetpackgallery.tag.info.xml), you have been working on how to extract the pages using XPath.

For your case you should have something like:

```
   <paging model="page">  
     <start id="page" default="1" />  
     <pagesize id="per_page" max="10" />  
     <total default="10" />  
   </paging>
```

The `per_page` would be in your internal query but it's used for the YQL to determine the queries needed. Then in your JavaScript could probably do something like:

```
   y.query(
       "select * from html where url=@url",
       {url: "http://jetpackgallery.mozillalabs.com/jetpacks?page=" + page}
       );
```